# How to add shadow to a GMSMarker?

Tags: ios, ios8, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to add some **shadow** to the markers on my GMSMapView but configuring the shadow properties of GMSMarkerLayer does not appear to have any effect.

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
[marker setMap:self.mapView];
marker.snippet = @"Description";
marker.title = @"Title";
marker.position = busData.location.coordinate;
marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BusMarker"];
marker.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
marker.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
marker.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
marker.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

I'm setting the same properties I'd use on a CALayer object, as GMSMarkerLayer subclasses CALayer.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? I'm using SDK version 1.10.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`iconView`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#use_the_markers_iconview_property) property and draw shadow inside that view (keeping it in bounds of `iconView`).

Answer (score 0):

The thing to understand here is the Google Maps on iOS is implemented in OpenGL. As such, changing the default properties of [GMSMarkerLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker_layer#details) has no visual effect. Sorry about that.

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Not actual, but it is answer:

```
-(UIImage *)makeShadowImage:(UIImage *) image;
{
    CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    imageLayer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;

    [imageLayer setShadowColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [imageLayer setShadowOpacity:0.5];
    [imageLayer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
    [imageLayer setShadowRadius:4.0];
    imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return roundedImage;
}
```